# Select Rows based on a condition in Pandas dataframe with groupby

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as below -

```
    Federation  Game        Medal_each_game
0   AFG         Athletics   1.00
1   AFG         Boxing      0.00
2   AFG         Football    1.00
3   AFG         Hockey      0.00
4   AFG         Taekwondo   2.00
5   AFG         Wrestling   0.00
6   AHO         Athletics   0.00
7   AHO         Boxing      3.00
8   AHO         Fencing     2.00
9   AHO         Football    0.00
```

I need to find highest medal count per 'federation' and get the 'Game'

output should be something like this

```
  Federation    Game        Medal_each_game
0   AFG         Taekwondo   2.00
1   AHO         Boxing      3.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby_idxmax`:

```
>>> df.loc[df.groupby('Federation')['Medal_each_game'].idxmax()]

  Federation       Game  Medal_each_game
4        AFG  Taekwondo              2.0
7        AHO     Boxing              3.0
```

Comment: It looks super easy, thanks man! was spending a lot of time on it